# Using toggle in Powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am looking to use toggle and turn on/off based on if condition, I tried the following code but dint work as expected.

`If('User Input' > 'Output - Max' = "Yes","No")`

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit. Are you trying to use a toggle control in your app to display if the value input by the user in another control satisfies your condition?

Comment: If have have Textbox 1 value of "1" and Textbox 2 Value of "2", if the Textbox 1 value is greater than Textbox 2 the toggle should show as "Yes" else "No"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you should configure your toggle control like this:

1. Displaymode: `Displaymode.View`
2. Default: `Value(Textbox1.Text) > Value(Textbox2.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to solve this problem:

If you are expecting users to enter only numbers in the text input control, it is better to use the Number format for your text input control like:

[image]

Then you can set `Default` property of toggle control simply to:

```
Textbox1.Text > Textbox2.Text
```